# Whenever I execute terminal command from code it gives "cannot run program" error=2 No such file or directory

Tags: java, macos, unix, command

Using this code and getting error:
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(“(lsof -i:10723 | grep node | awk ‘{print $2;}’)“);

```
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

        // read the output from the command
        String s = null;
        System.out.println(“Here is the standard output of the command:\n”);
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        // read any errors from the attempted command

        System.out.println(“Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n”);
        while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot do this:

```
exec("(lsof -i:10723 | grep node | awk '{print $2;}')");
```

The `exec` method does not understand shell syntax.  It will split that command string into a command name and arguments where it sees whitespace.

So the name of the command that `exec` tries to execute is `(lsof` ... which does not exist.  Hence the error message.

If you want to run a pipeline using `exec`, the simple way is to use a shell; e.g.

```
exec(new String[] {"sh", "-c",
                   "(lsof -i:10723 | grep node | awk '{print $2;}')"})
```

Comment: Thanks that worked for me :)

Comment: String command[]={"/bin/sh", "-c","adb devices"};   But when I am trying to execute adb commands it is giving me "/bin/sh: adb: command not found

Comment: That means that `adb` is either  not installed, or not your shell's default `$PATH`.  For the former: install it!  For the latter, either change the default path, or use the absolute pathname for the `adb` command.  Please note that this question is a Java question, not an Android question.  There may be something Android specific in what yiou are trying to do that means that the above advice does not apply.